# Child nodes not accepted

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing on a program in C# that'll take data from a server, write it into a file and then read the file to grab the data contained.
The last part is the problem. I get my XML-file stream and the XML file seems to be fine but except for the root node, my program doesn't accept any child nodes even though in a list it counts all the 700 child nodes. Was checking my spelling, the adressing, the tree... nothing worked so far.

XML Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uniprot xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://uniprot.org/uniprot http://www.uniprot.org/support/docs/uniprot.xsd">
  <entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="2005-03-01" modified="2013-10-16" version="51">
    <accession>P69430</accession>
    <accession>O65938</accession>
    <accession>P27856</accession>
    <name>TATA_ECO57</name>
    <protein>
      <recommendedName>
        <fullName>Sec-independent protein translocase protein TatA</fullName>
      </recommendedName>
    </protein>
```

program:

```
Datapath = startupPath + "\\" + Data[0, 0] + ".xml"; 
XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XMLdoc.Load(Datapath); 
 XmlNodeList xnList = XMLdoc.SelectNodes("//*"); //the list shows all 700 entries so the path etc are correct
var node = XMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("uniprot/entry/protein/recommendedName/fullName").InnerText;
```

As soon as I try to adress any child node from uniprot, it's just null which drives me mad. Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the namespace?

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://uniprot.org/uniprot");
        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:exampleNode", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//uniprot//entry/protein/recommendedName  /fullName");
 node.InnerXml;